# R fitdist/optim Error code 1

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

Does anybody knows if there is some additonal information when the `fitdist` function failed with `error code 1`.

I guess this means: 
`error Code 1`  indicates that the iteration limit maxit had been reached inside the `optim`Alghorithmus.

What can I change in my `fitdist`function apart from the starting parameters, to prevent a further error?

Comment: Could you provide us some code to work on?